# how to use "Of doing so" in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

how to use "of doing so" in a sentence?

example

**Even though we are happy to change the battery, unfortunately, there is a risk of doing so because of a cracked LCD**

is it used correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Think about the difference between the risk **of** doing something and the risk **in** doing something.

Answer (score 1):

No.  If you say "a risk of {something}"  that means there is a chance that {somthing} will happen (and that something is bad):  "There is a risk of a thunderstorm in the afternoon."

"Doing so" refers back to "changing the battery".  So literally what you are saying is "There a chance of changing the battery (and changing the battery is bad)".

You can fix this by specifying what the actual risk is

> ... there is a risk of damage to the screen because of a cracked LCD.

Or you can use "a risk in ...". The phrase "a risk in {something}" means that if you do {something} there is a chance of something bad happening: "There's a risk in crossing the road, so look both ways."

> We are happy to change the battery. Unfortunately there is a risk in doing so because of the cracked LCD.

These are two sentences, not one. Try to have just one introductory phrase. It is simpler and clearer.

Comment: I know it's just an example sentence, but I've taken a few mobile phones apart, and there isn't really anything linking changing the battery and an already cracked screen, in terms of 'risk'. The screen isn't going to get more cracked; it's ruined already; the battery isn't going to explode or fail because of that. I wonder, is the intended meaning 'There's no point in changing the battery because the screen is cracked and the phone is, therefore, worthless'?